# Sorting Changes with View

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sorting

We have this view which we use to export results out via BCP.  It was working for the longest time now the data is not sorted properly

The view vwEFTFileData is defined as

```
select TOP (100) PERCENT e.EftRecord   
from EftFileData e  (readuncommitted) 
order by EftRecordID
```

It is readuncommitted because we call the bcp under a transaction

Now I added two debug statements to the procedure

```
select * from  dbo.vwEFTFileData
```

This come back with a sort order different then expected

```
select TOP (100) PERCENT e.EftRecord   
from EftFileData e  (readuncommitted) 
order by EftRecordID
```

This returns the table in the expected order.

I am at a loss at this point.  Both commands are under the same transaction.  I don't think it is a bcp issue as the sort order is still incorrect outside of bcp.

Comment: Views aren't sorted in the relational model. That just gets optimised out since after SQL Server 2000 except if a trace flag is present. You need an `order by` in the query that selects from the view for guaranteed results. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx

Comment: Take a look at the execution plan - your TOP (100) PERCENT ... ORDER BY in the view are just a mind trick; they are actually optimized away, because the ORDER BY is used to determine which rows to include, not how they are presented. And since SQL Server knows you're getting all rows, it doesn't need to care how they're selected. See https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions (#3), and https://sqlblog.org/2012/02/28/why-people-think-some-sql-server-2000-behaviors-live-on-12-years-later

Comment: Change your view to just `SELECT e.EftRecord FROM dbo.EftFileData;` and then change your *query* to `SELECT EftRecord /* why *? */ FROM dbo.vwEFTFileData;`. Or skip the view altogether and just put the isolation hint on the query (or at session scope).

Comment: If there is a clustered index on `EftRecordID`, you can use `-h "order(EftRecordID)"` from `bcp` to sort it. (And if you're selecting from the view it must be a materialized view with a unique clustered key to use this).

Comment: It's just weird that it was working for almost a year.  As for skipping the view, we went with the view because the same query is used across different procedures.  The second select works and doesn't need the top 100